# How to prevent form submission when submit event is handled using .on() method

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form inside of a page that uses jQuery Mobile.

It's just a good ol' form, nothing fancy:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

If I add following to a script block (note: enclosing $(function(){}); is omitted for clarity):

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    // event.preventDefault(); doesn't work here?!?
    return false;
});
```

...form will not be submitted, no matter what. However, this approach can not be used with jQuery Mobile, because after page is changed, event binding will not be applied when DOM is changed.

So, if I try this approach instead:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event){
    // event.preventDefault(); doesn't work here as well...
    alert('submit!');
    return false;
});
```

...Form WILL be submitted, even though it returns false (and there is alert when button is clicked).

What's going on here, and how to get expected behavior?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `return false` causes the form not to be submitted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5M2Sg/).

Comment: Hmmm, out of interest why are you using `on` for an event on a single element? I thought the whole benefit of using `on` was when attaching it to multiple elements, or a selector with elements that are not present on document ready?

Comment: @mattytommo - nope, on() can be used with any handler, delegated or not, that's the real benefit of it.

Comment: @adeneo I know it can be used with a single element, but I thought the benefits around using it were geared around the usage of multiple elements?

Comment: @DavidHedlund perhaps it has something to do with jquery-mobile being used on page as well, I didn't test it thoroughly.

Comment: @mattytommo I hope I'm not answering to something you didn't ask. The reason why I'm using .on() here (aside from the fact that I'm also using it on multiple elements elsewhere) is the benefit that .on() will handle events even *after* DOM tree has been manipulated. It lets you configure event handler for tree elements that aren't present in DOM, which can be added later, which isn't possible with traditional .bind().

Comment: @mr.b Ah yeah that wasn't what I was asking, but never mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of attaching handler to form, do it for the Submit button.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

would surely prevent form submission & once you are done validating (or whatever you wish to do before form submission), you can trigger form submission using

```
$('#target').submit();
```